# Javascript return same value in then and catch

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

In JS, let's say I call a promise in a 'fire and forget' way. I don't care if it was successful or not, and I don't care what it returns as I want to return the same value anyways.

I can call

`return myPromise().then(() => foo).catch(() => foo);`

Is there a way to not repeat then `then` and `catch` parts?

#### What I've tried

I thought about using `finally`, thinking that it will take what finally returns (similar to what Java does by taking the return value of the finally block) :
`return myPromise().finally(() => foo);`
But it turns out it didn't do what I expected. According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally#return_value), this return value will be used to reject in case the original promise rejected.

Comment: `myPromise().catch(() => {}).then(() => foo)`?

Comment: @deceze Isn't that, apart from order, exactly the same as the OP's? Just wondering if I'm missing anything. For the OP: I don't think you will find something more succinct.

Comment: @somethinghere it's not exactly the same, since `foo` is only specified to be returned once, not in both the catch and then.

Comment: @VLAZ but it's almost as verbose and it's a little bit less explicit

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eLuhc2xw/

Comment: @Ricola You were trying to avoid the repetition of the `foo` expression, didn't you? That's exactly what deceze's code does. I'd argue it's even *more* explicit, since it spells out "*ignore any error, then always return `foo`*".

Comment: True. This can be posted as an answer, I'll accept it. I was mainly looking for something more succinct but I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) if you're targeting newer browsers or Node.js versions.

This function will return a Promise that resolves whether or not the passed Promise resolves or rejects.

```js
  
function foo(results) { 
    console.log('foo():', ...results)
}

// Success path
Promise.allSettled([Promise.resolve('Yay')]).then(foo)

// Failure path
Promise.allSettled([Promise.reject('Doh')]).then(foo)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your result returning function once and then re-use it twice for the `.then()` and `.catch()` handlers

```
const myReturn = () => foo;

return myPromise()
    .then(myReturn)
    .catch(myReturn);
```

You can further shorten this by using [both parameters of `.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#parameters) which handle both the success and failure path:

```
const myReturn = () => foo;

return myPromise()
    .then(myReturn, myReturn);
```

---

If you find needing this a lot, you might make a small library function that takes a value and returns two functions that both just evaluate to it:

```
const doubleThunk = val =>
  [() => val, () => val];
```

Which would be used like this:

```
return myPromise()
    .then(...doubleThunk(foo));
```

Answer (score 1):

From [@deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)'s comment and [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) clarification:

```
myPromise()
.catch(() => {}) // ignore any error 
.then(() => foo) // always return foo
```